# Git - BUG: refs/files-backend.c:465: returning non-zero -1, should have set myerr! On branch main

Tags: git, git-bash

I have copy-pasted some files into my directory where I have git, and when I ran a command `git status` it gave me this error message.

```
BUG: refs/files-backend.c:465: returning non-zero -1, should have set myerr!
On branch main
```

When I restored everything with `git restore .`, the message still remains.

I have tried to find the meaning of the bug, but I haven’t found anything.

Comment: AFAIK the `BUG` part indicates that this is an unexpected problem with git itself and not something that you did wrong. If you look at [the code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/refs/files-backend.c#L465) it looks like `parse_loose_ref_content` returned -1 but didn't set `myerr` (which apparently is breaking some convention). My guess is that you've run into a genuine bug in git and need to file that. Digging a bit deeper it looks like [`FETCH_HEAD` has a problem](https://github.com/git/git/blob/main/refs/files-backend.c#L490).

Comment: You've encountered a bug in Git. Send the bug details to whoever maintains your particular Git release (Git-for-Widows if you're using that, or the regular Git mailing list if you're building Git from source yourself, or whatever).

Comment: @JoachimSauer `parse_loose_ref_contents` sets `myerr` (called `failure_errno` inside that function) on all paths where it returns a non-zero value. It seems there has to be a different bug.

Comment: @hoffmale: true, seems I'm pretty rusty with reading C code. It's also quite possible that OP is using a different version. But the main point stands: it's a bug in git and needs to be treated like that.

Comment: I have created an issue for this bug: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3674

Comment: Thank you all for your support. Thanks @hoffmale for creating an issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [release 2.35.1(2)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.35.1.windows.2) seems to fix this issue, through [PR 3678](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/3678)

Context: [issue 3655](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3655) and [issue 3674](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3674) (the last one is mentioned in the comments).

> A bug in FSCache

See [commit 5437f0f](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/3678/commits/5437f0fd368c7faf1a0b5e1fef048232c1f2a3e6)

> In `fscache_lstat()`, we did not set `errno` upon a cache miss (which
> indicates that the item did not exist at the time the `lstat()` values
> were cached), and therefore we now trigger this problem all the time.
>
> Let's set `errno=ENOENT` when no entry was found.

Comment: Running `choco upgrade git` to upgrade to 2.35 + worked for me

Comment: @PeterG Well done. Although on Windows, the command `git update-git-for-windows` should work too (without relying on a third party app manager).